# ParameterDecorator: Retrieve parameter type

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, decorator, typescript-decorator

I'm writing a little library using typescript decorator and I'm not able to retrieve parameter type. I'm using "reflect-metadata" library.

This is a class that use decorators:

```js
interface IParamInterface {
    foo: string;
    bar: string;
}

@ClassDecorator()
class MyClass {
    @MethodDecorator()
    myMethod(@ParamDecorator() param: IParamInterface)
}
```

And at runtime, using decorators, I want to retrieve `param` type (`IParamInterface`) In order to call a function (so i need to bind a function somewhere) when `myMethod` is being called.

```js
const instance = new MyClass();

let prototype = Object.getPrototypeOf(instance);
let properties = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(prototype);

for (let property of properties) {
    //Retrieve parameter metadata for method 'myMethod'
    const paramMetadata = Reflect.getMetadata('param_decorator', instance[property]);
    //Retrieve myMethod arguments
    const arguments = instance[property].arguments
}
```

But I can't do that because the compiler says:

`'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them`

Is there a smart way to do that?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: The `arguments` property is only available inside of a function call. I don't understand why you need to use it here.

Comment: I found another way to retrieve arguments using metadata.